# How is “mechanism” split (hyphenated) at the end of the line?

Tags: spelling, hyphens

How is “mechanism” split (hyphenated) at the end of the line?

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mechanism says `mech·a·nism` but

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mechanism?s=t says `mech·an·ism`.

Where can I split the word at the end of a line? Is the difference between the on-line sources about British versus American English (which one is which), or is one simply wrong, or what circumstances do I have to pay attention for to determine which one to choose? (If there is a third, better, free on-line resource, naming its url for future use is also welcome!)

Comment: I din' get the question. Are you talking about the pronunciation? If yes, it depends how you speak it.

Comment: @MaulikV OP's talking about soft hyphens in word-breaking line wrapping http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Word_boundaries.2C_hyphenation.2C_and_hard_spaces

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/ might be of interest to you.

Comment: @MaulikV: Kreiri is right. Please excuse me for not communicating that clearly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are [some rules about word division](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000129.htm).

Rule 1 is to split between syllables, and that's what 'mech·a·nism' does.  However, rule 3 is that prefixes and suffixes make natural divides and that's what 'mech·an·ism' does.

In general though, word breaks should match up with the pronunciation of the word, and the pronunciation guides from the dictionaries are clear that the n sound stays with 'nism'.  So while either hyphenation is potentially OK, the first one is likely to be the better choice.

The [Oxford Style Guide](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/secondary/harts_rules/3-4-word-division) on word division has some more examples.

Comment: +1 & thank you! Note: the Oxford Style Guide requires a subscription. - Syllables and pronunciation are possible issues for an ELL (like me), thus also thanks for the explanation regarding the specific case of "mechanism".

Comment: Note that Americans use different rules, for example they do not normally split a word after a short vowel.